# transforming a continous respond variable into a discrete one

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution, continuous-data

I am visually estimating fish length underwater to convert it in fish biomass by means of proper length-weight relationships. Obviously, my accuracy is not perfect. When making hypothesis about factors affecting fish biomass, would it be right to round the biomass data at the nearest integer and therefore being able to work with Poisson or negative binomial distributions in predictive models?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by rounding? It cannot improve the accuracy.

Comment: The rounding will add more measurement error.  And why would you prefer to use Poisson or negative binomial distributions?

Answer (score 5):

Fish length and fish biomass are not counts, they are measurements, so it must be better to model them as measurements. For example, with usual linear regressions, or some extensions of that, Poisson or negative binomial regression do not seem natural. Rounding to get integers can only lose information.

For a more detailed answer you will need to tell us more!

Comment: I strongly agree that rounding will lose info' (+1). While I think I can understand "count" vs "not count", I didn't understand what  you were driving at with "count" vs "measurement". Unless we're talking some theoretical math, I would have said that all count (data) are also measurements. But I'm open to learning more about where you're coming at this from. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Galen: Maybe you can think about counts also as measurements ... I have been teaching at a teachers college, and there counting and measuring is seen as different activities, since it is so in basic school ...

Comment: Interesting! In that educational context, how are counts and measurements defined?

Comment: @Galen: Think of this in the context of small children learning, then counting is what gives us natural numbers, while measurements, in this context typically of length, weight, ... gives decimal numbers (in principle, at least, counting is exact, while measurement always have an associated measurement error. When counts becomes large, of course this difference disappears, and the difference becomes less meaningful)

Comment: Ah, thank you for providing that context. I can see how there are many counting problems that have this sense of exactness which measuring things like length, angle, concentration do not seem to have.

Comment: One example of measurement error on count data I encountered in forestry is counting trees. It is pretty easy to count trees in an  mature stand of douglas fir because the shade cover and soil acidification they cause makes them really stand out, but counting small trees (e.g. saplings or recently planted trees) while trying to be fast is an error-prone exercise. I think our contracts at that time said the surveyors had to be within 20% of the auditors. One nasty problem is what they call a cedar carpet. Its when you have hundreds or thousands of cedar sapling covering the plot area...

Comment: Another example is from my college days studying biotechnology. We would have to count different white blood cells in some prepared samples, and get a close enough answer to the instructor's number. That is about 10 years ago now so I hardly remember them all, but they included things like eosinophils, basophils, neutrophils, lymphocytes, and monocytes. There was a combo of getting the count right, but also the classification error of getting the right count for each class of cell.